# MongoEngine - Have a 'virtual' model with complex dependencies?

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have an issue where there are two sets of users for one set of MongoEngine documents. One of these uses sets wants complex helper functions to be part of the document definition, the other user set cannot install the dependencies that the those functions require.

I want to achieve something like a clean model and a dirty model where the user can select for themselves, but the actual database document definition is maintained in only one place. E.g.

---

CleanModel/my_document.py

```
class MyDocument(Document):
    my_field = StringField()
```

---

DirtyModel/my_document.py

```
from CleanModel import MyDocument as _MyDocument

class MyDocument(_MyDocument):
    def some_function_that_relies_on_compiled_code():
        pass
```

---

The use could then do:

```
from DirtyModel import MyDocument
```

or

```
from CleanModel import MyDocument
```

and work with exactly the same Mongo document. The way I've written it above, `DirtyModel.MyDocument.objects()` can't get at documents created with the `CleanModel`.

Any ideas on the best way to solve this? (I don't think that moving the helper methods outside of the document definition is practical in this case)

Comment: I think I'm going to fix it with monkey patching. I'm sure there's a better way but I don't know it.